# logging info in customized package does not show when call from main?

Tags: python, logging

I created my own package "foo", and I am calling the functions/classes from "main.py".

I set up logging config in main.py:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s-%(levelname)s-%(message)s')
```

I have used logging in foo.
I do not know how to set it up properly so that when I call foo.function() from main, I can see the logging info in foo.function.
Thanks for help!
in foo.py, I did:

```
import logging
def test_logging():
    logging.info('hi from foo!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place your logging configuration in [**init**.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) or place it in main function (see example [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules)).